# How to generate HTML table using RenderSnake library in Java?

Tags: java, html, list

I am trying to use [Render Snake](http://rendersnake.org/examples.html) HTML library to programatically generate HTML for me. I am trying to make HTML table by using Render Snake as shown below - This is just an example of how do we make table using Render Snake library.

```
html
.table(class_("city-table"))
  .tr()
    .th().content("City")
    .th().content("Country")
    ._tr()
  .tr()
    .td().content("Amsterdam")
    .td().content("The Netherlands")
    ._tr()
._table();
```

I need to do the same thing while iterating my object and make the proper `.tr` and close it as well. So this is what confusing me a lot.

Below is the way I would like to have my table in an HTML using RenderSnake library - Here `PoolName`, `TotalSyncCount`, `TotalAsyncCount`, `SyncNinetyFivePercentile` and `AsyncNinetyFivePercentile` are my column names so I am using `th` for them

```
PoolName    TotalSyncCount  TotalAsyncCount SyncNinetyFivePercentile    AsyncNinetyFivePercentile

Hello          100              100             4                           0
World          300              300             2                           0
```

And below is my object which has all these details and which I need to iterate to get the table in the above format

```
public class PoolMetrics {

    private String poolName;
    private String totalSyncCount;
    private String totalAsyncCount;
    private String syncNinetyFivePercentile;
    private String asyncNinetyFivePercentile;

    // getters and setters
}
```

And so far I am able to create only the column names using `RenderSnake`. I am not sure how to add values inside those column names by iterating `PoolMetrics` object -

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    List<PoolMetrics> poolMetricsList = new ArrayList<PoolMetrics>();

    // here poolMetricsList has all the information as shown above in the table

    HtmlCanvas html = new HtmlCanvas();
    html.html().body().table().tr().th().content("PoolName").th().content("TotalSyncCount").th()
            .content("TotalAsyncCount").th().content("SyncNinetyFivePercentile").th()
            .content("AsyncNinetyFivePercentile")._tr()._table()._body()._html();

    // now how do I iterate poolMetricsList to add values inside the column names
    // as shown in the above table
}
```

**Problem Statement:-**

How do I iterate `poolMetricsList` object and add the proper values for those column names using RenderSnake? I would like to generate my HTML as shown above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that each method call returns the same instance of `HtmlCanvas` (not immutable), so each call you make `tr()`, `td()`, `_html()` etc. is handled internally and you are returned the current instance.

This makes chaining awesome, but also does not *require* you to chain your calls.

Having said that, here is a complete example:

```
public class RendersnakeTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        List<PoolMetrics> poolMetricsList = new ArrayList<>();
        poolMetricsList.add(new PoolMetrics("A", "0", "0", "0", "0"));
        poolMetricsList.add(new PoolMetrics("A", "1", "1", "1", "1"));
        poolMetricsList.add(new PoolMetrics("A", "2", "2", "2", "2"));
        poolMetricsList.add(new PoolMetrics("A", "3", "3", "3", "3"));
        poolMetricsList.add(new PoolMetrics("A", "4", "4", "4", "4"));

        HtmlCanvas html = new HtmlCanvas();
        html.html().body().table().tr().th().content("PoolName").th().content("TotalSyncCount").th()
                .content("TotalAsyncCount").th().content("SyncNinetyFivePercentile").th()
                .content("AsyncNinetyFivePercentile")._tr();

        // add the rows
        for (PoolMetrics pool : poolMetricsList) {
            html.tr()
                    .td(class_("city-table")).content(pool.getPoolName())
                    .td().content(pool.getTotalAsyncCount())
                    .td().content(pool.getTotalSyncCount())
                    .td().content(pool.getSyncNinetyFivePercentile())
                    .td().content(pool.getAsyncNinetyFivePercentile())
                ._tr();
        }

        // close the table
        html._table()._body()._html();

        // write the file
        final String rendered = html.toHtml();
        final File output = new File("c:/output.html");
        Files.write(output.toPath(), rendered.getBytes("UTF-8"), StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING);
    }

}

class PoolMetrics {

    private String poolName;
    private String totalSyncCount;
    private String totalAsyncCount;
    private String syncNinetyFivePercentile;
    private String asyncNinetyFivePercentile;

    public PoolMetrics(String poolName, String totalSyncCount, String totalAsyncCount, String syncNinetyFivePercentile, String asyncNinetyFivePercentile) {
        this.poolName = poolName;
        this.totalSyncCount = totalSyncCount;
        this.totalAsyncCount = totalAsyncCount;
        this.syncNinetyFivePercentile = syncNinetyFivePercentile;
        this.asyncNinetyFivePercentile = asyncNinetyFivePercentile;
    }

    public String getPoolName() {
        return poolName;
    }

    public String getTotalSyncCount() {
        return totalSyncCount;
    }

    public String getTotalAsyncCount() {
        return totalAsyncCount;
    }

    public String getSyncNinetyFivePercentile() {
        return syncNinetyFivePercentile;
    }

    public String getAsyncNinetyFivePercentile() {
        return asyncNinetyFivePercentile;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

the `class_` method is provided by a static import, it is actually contained within the abstract class `HtmlAttributesFactory`, to import these, add the following to your imports list:

```
import static org.rendersnake.HtmlAttributesFactory.*;
```

I have updated the example to include this as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot epoch for the help. It works like a charm. One more thing if you can help out by any chance. How would I add `css` on my table using this library?

Comment: In general, I would like to use this [css](http://codepen.io/geoffyuen/pen/FCBEg) in my above table using `RenderSnake` library.

Comment: Yeah I saw that but how would I add it here? In general what is this? `class_("city-table")`

Comment: it adds a class attribute to specified HTML element, i.e `<td class="city-table">`

Comment: I see but where does it find this class attribute in the Java code? If possible can you provide a simple example by which I can make this change?

Comment: @user2809564, see my update. :) i agree, they don't really make this clear in the documentation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61075/discussion-between-user2809564-and-epoch).

Comment: cool that makes lot of sense but then how it will apply my css which I want to use? Meaning where does city-table resides? And how does it know which css to use? Any idea?

Comment: Are you around? By any chance do you know my above question?

Comment: Hi there, you are asking multiple questions unrelated to the original, please create a new question if you are having problems. To answer your question: your css belongs in a .css file on the server, while your HTML references it, the browser applies the css styles according to how you defined it, in this case meaning the `.city-table { ... }` style declaration will be applied to all `td` elements that have the same class. I suggest you read up on the basics of HTML, CSS and web programming. Hope this answers your questions.

Comment: sorry for asking multiple questions. I am familiar with HTML and CSS but the confusion I have is - how does my html knows which css I need to use from RenderSnake library? And where does css will reside in my Java program?